# Is there a 'hello world' website for django? OR (I've installed django, now what)?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Python and decided to start familiarizing myself with the (defacto?) Python web framework - django.

I have successfully installed the latest release of django. I want a simple 'hello world' website that will get me up and running quickly. I am already familiar with web frameworks (albeit for different languages) - so I just need a simple 'hello world' example website to help me get going.

Ideally, I don't want to mess up with my Apache server settings (as I am still experimenting), so I want to use the lightweight web server that django bundles. I cant seem to find how to do this on the django website though - no doubt someone will post a link and shame me ...

So, does anyone know of a link that shows how to get a simple 'hello world' django website up and running with minimal fuss?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Next step? The (free, online and excellent) [Django book](http://djangobook.com/the-django-book/).

Comment: Looks like it's no longer around. In which case, the Django Girls tutorial https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/ gets excellent feedback

Answer (score 3):

[Writing your first Django app, part 1](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) was a lot of help.

Answer (score 2):

"Hello World" of django is the "[Polls and Votes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)"

Comment: What happens if we want a simple website? How do you know what to concider an app

Answer (score 1):

I think the [official tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) says it all...

```
cd /path/to/your/code
python django-admin.py startproject mysite  #creates dir 'mysite'
python manage.py runserver
```